# PHP connecting to SQL Server on localhost returns Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

EDIT: Sorry, I figured out what the problem was. I was editing the wrong file.

I'm (trying) to use PHP 5.3.5 to connect to my SQL SERVER 2005 but it has been nothing but trouble. On the local machine, if I use `SQLCMD -S (local) -U sqlUser -P 1234 -d MyTable` it connects fine. But the following code produces an error:

```
<?php
$myServer = "(local)";
$myUser = "sqlUser";
$myPass = "1234";
$myDB = "MyTable"; 
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=> $myDB, "UID" => $myUser, "PWD" => $myPass);


//connection to the database
try{
$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo)
  or die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}catch(Exception $e){
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($e);
     echo "</pre>";
     die;
}
?>
```

How can I get php to connect to my SQL Server?

Full Error:

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => HYT00
            [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        )

)
```

Comment: Please repost the error dump as it appears when you view source on your page so it is formatted readably.

Comment: @Michael-Sorry, I just updated with the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, I was editing the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP doesn't use the same method to connect as SQLCMD you'll be seeing odd results. Doesn't PHP just use TCPIP to connect (meaning your server should be setup to listen on TCPIP as well).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying. I believe I have it set up to listen on TCPIP.